# Why is javac's -cp option case sensitive, but java's -cp option not?

Tags: java, classpath, javac, case-sensitive

I've noticed that case sensitivity for `javac` and `java` options seem to vary.  For instance:

Case sensitive `javac` command option?

```
-cp          Yes
-sourcepath  Yes
-d           No
```

Case sensitive `java` command option?

```
-cp          No
```

As an example of case sensitivity for these four options, take the following folder structure:

```
project \ src \ Main.java
              \ subf \ Sub.java
        \ bin \ Main.class
              \ subf \ Sub.class
```

Main.java, which shows the Sub class being used -

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subf.Sub.method();
    }
}
```

Also, take the following batch file, which uses `javac` and `java`:

```
javac -cp bin -sourcepath src -d bin src\Main.java
java -cp bin Main
```

If I delete all precompiled `.class` files inside this project, and rename the source code sub folder called `subf` to `SUBF`, then when I run the batch file above, I get a compilation error, as it can't find the package called `subf`.  So, `javac`'s `-sourcepath` option is case sensitive.

(In order for the next test to succeed and run, an existing `Sub.class` file needs to be moved back in to the `bin\subf` folder.)  If I leave the renamed source code `subf` folder as `SUBF`, so that the source code can't be compiled, and rename the bin class folder called `subf` to `SUBF`, then when I run the batch file, I get an error (`can't find package subf`) for compilation, but the executable runs OK.  So, `javac`'s `-cp` option is case sensitive, but `java`'s `-cp` option isn't.  (Please note that as per the title of this SO question, this observation forms the basis of my question.)

Finally, if I rename the source code `SUBF` folder back to `subf`, so that the source code can be compiled, but leave the class folder called `subf` as `SUBF`, then when I run the batch file, I don't get any errors - the batch file compiles and also runs.  This means that `javac`'s `-d` option is not case sensitive, as it overlooks the fact that the class `subf` folder has been renamed to `SUBF`, as the `.class` file found inside that folder has an up to date datestamp value.

I have zipped up this simple project in to a download.  It can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd415zl9rb5cda3/project.7z) (on DropBox).

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive when it comes to matching package and class names.  **Everything** Java does here is case sensitive.

However, the file system on Windows is not case sensitive.  It is [case preserving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation) but not case sensitive.  This means that a request for a file named `A.class` would find a file called `a.class` if it existed.

This explains why some things that Java does appear to be ignoring case.  The `javac` or `java` program asks for a directory, and the operating system searches for it by ignoring case.

But you cannot rely on this to always be true.  On another operating system that does not ignore case, Java may fail to find files that it would find under Windows.

---

There was one thing you did that affects the outcome of your commands:

You should pass all the Java file names to the compiler.  If you were building with `ant`, this would have been done for you.

```
> javac -cp bin -sourcepath src -d bin src\Main.java
src\Main.java:5: package subf does not exist
        subf.Sub.method();
```

Do it this way and there are no errors:

```
> javac -cp bin -sourcepath src -d bin src\Main.java src\SUBF\Sub.java
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm still curious as to why the same `-cp` option used with `javac` and `java` causes "opposing outcomes" that I describe in my question.

Comment: I think the answer to that is, Java will ask the operating system to list the file/folder names.  The names are reported to Java with the correct case.  Then Java will remember these names, and when it does a string compare against the desired package name, it will not match, so it reports the error that the package does not exist.