# How to ensure case-sensitive resource is what I look for on a case-insensitive file system?

Tags: java

I have a program which needs to lookup resources using `ClassLoader#getResource(String)`. The program normally works fine but on a Windows machine I'm running into a problem. I broke it down to property of the file system being case-insensitive. Normally, **several paths are tried** to look for the correct file. On a case-insensitive system, however, it is possible the **wrong file is matched**. In my program, resource names are **case-sensitive**, so the returned file on a case-insensitive system can be wrong if it has different capitalization.

For example: I am looking for bar/Foo.class and get back a file bar/FOO.class. I need to **recognize this case and reject it**.

What is the best way to check if the returned URL fits my specified path **in a case-sensitive** manner?

I was thinking about comparing the specified path with the result of getPath of the URL. But nothing anywhere tells me if the resulting URL will use my given path or the real path. Thus, unless someone shows me documentation that this is different and specified, I cannot be sure this will always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact you're not using absolute paths to find a certain resource. Therefor, the answer to your question is simply *you can't*. To a case insensitive system, there can only be one file at the path "bar/foo.class" **from any one context**. The only way there can be multiple files at such a path is if they have different absolute paths (e.g. /a/bar/foo.class and /b/bar/foo.class), in which case they have a **different context** (=there are two different folders "bar" which both contain a file named "foo.class").

When searching all resources matching a non-absolute path (like bar/foo.class), there is absolutely no guarantee there will only be one file on the system that matches that path (matches meaning the file's absolute path contains the path you specified). Further more, if there are multiple matches, there is no guarantee that they will differ in capitalization, so using case sensitivity to verify which file is wrong is not a good approach. Moreover, to a case insensitive system both files have the same name but are just at a different absolute location (but the same relative location to a different context [read: folder]).

If possible, search for files using their absolute path. That way, only the file with identical capitalization will be matched on case sensitive systems and the one file (if there is one) at that absolute path will be matched on case insensitive systems. I hope this answer is more useful to you.

Comment: If I wold be looking for /a/bar/foo.class and where to find a file Foo.class, it would still be wrong in my code logic. My problem is not finding multiple bar/foo.class files and then being unable to decide between /a/bar/foo.class and /b/bar/foo.class. That kind of problem can be solved with for example getResources instead of getResource. My problem is that the foo.class I found really is a FOO.class and I am looking for a safe way of knowing the the case sensitive name. Just because the file system is case insensitive does not mean there is no sensitive name

Comment: Okay, I see, but just out of curiosity, if the system is case insensitive, why do you want to have the case sensitive name of the resource again? I understand case sensitivity is important to you and I fully understand it is on a case sensitive system, but if the system is case insensitive then what does it really matter?

Comment: let's makea Java style example... say you have `import foo.*; import bar.*; class X extends Foo{}` and let's say you have additional source files foo/FOO.java and bar/Foo.java. You compile only the source I gave and otherwise let Java pickup the additional source files automatically. Case insensitive means, that the java compiler will fail this compilation because foo.FOO and bar.Foo is ambiguous by file name. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683691/why-is-javacs-cp-option-case-sensitive-but-javas-cp-option-not.

Comment: Reading the comments there make me wonder if I have not phrased the question wrong... I am not dealing with a case-insensitive file system... it is case preserving, just not case-sensitive

Comment: Well that is a whole different thing... regardless, letting the system search for "Foo" might return "FOO" (due to case insensitive matching), even though it is case preserving, because you are still looking for a relative path (here a file name) instead of looking for the full path (which would be "bar/Foo". Imagine both files were capitalized as "Foo.class", so "bar/Foo" and "foo/Foo", then even if you could check the capitalization, you could still have a mismatch. Hence I think using capitalization is not the right way to solve your problem, but expanding paths is.

Comment: having a conflict like bar/Foo and foo/Foo is perfectly fine to me. There is not a single, all deciding path